# How to pass two different instances of the same class to two different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, hashcode, runnable

I have a question regarding threads that I have searched for a solution but couldn't get clarified.
Consider I have a Runnable class

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
String x = "";
public MyThread (String s) { 
    x = s;
  }

  public void run() { 
     // x = "hello";
      System.out.println("runobject: "+this.hashCode());
      System.out.println("runstring: "+x.hashCode());
    System.out.println("x: "+ x); 
      } 
}
```

I have another class having the main method as

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestThread {
    public static void main (String arg[]) { 

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThread("John"));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyThread("Mike"));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

The above code gives output as

```
runobject: 33810571
runstring: 2314539
x: John
runobject: 33810633
runstring: 2398230
x: Mike
```

Now in `theMyThread` class, if I remove the assignment of `x` in the constructor and bring in the assignment `x = "hello";` in the run method like below

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    String x = "";
    public MyThread (String s) { 
        //x = s;
      }

      public void run() { 
          x = "hello";
          System.out.println("runobject: "+this.hashCode());
          System.out.println("runstring: "+x.hashCode());
        System.out.println("x: "+ x); 
      } 
}
```

the output that I get is

```
runobject: 33810572
runstring: 99162322
x: hello
runobject: 33810634
runstring: 99162322
x: hello
```

***Note: In the second case, the hashcode of the x variable is same in both threads.Please explain the above scenario. Why in the second case, both the threads are referring to the same x variable and generating same hashcode??***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the output, how do you know that both threads refer to the same "hello"?

Comment: String is immutable, as such the hashCode() of any given (compile time) String will be the same. See TimB's answer

Comment: @fajarkoe String literals live in the String pool and are reused to stop unnecessary creation of String objects. The only way they *wouldn't* be the same String object is if they were created using `new String("hello")` each time.

Answer (score 2):

String constants are stored in a cache. When you assign it you get assigned the same String constant from the cache no matter where or when you assign it.

Do `new String("hello")` instead and you will get a different String.

Additionally `hashCode` and `equals` work off the value of the `String`. So no matter how many `Strings` you have or how you construct them if you have the `String` "hello" it will always respond the same to both `equals` and `hashCode`. That is actually what `equals` and `hashCode` are for - quickly finding things that have the same value.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeah, just finished adding something to cover that too.

Comment: I mean if the objects are different, the hashcode of the instance variable x should be different I believe?

Comment: @Anubhav Why do you believe so?

Comment: @Anubhav You've got a misunderstanding of Hash Codes then. Objects with a different value should ideally have different Hash Codes (it's not required) but objects with the same value must have the same Hash Code.

Comment: Ok, I understand the question and the discussion had become more specific towards `Strings`. Actually in the real code the variable x under question is an ArrayList and it is assigned the required value in the Run() method like this: x = _a function that returns ArrayList_. How will this discussed scenario behave in the case of ArrayList because in the real code too, I am getting same hashcode but the mentioned function is taking in different arguments in each thread and returning different arraylist values in each thread.